# Sending two different email with one common attachment, get merged together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, email-attachments

I'm sending out two different e-mails:

```
mail(:to => email1, :template_name => "mail1_template",
         :subject => "Mail 1").deliver!
mail(:to => email2, :template_name => "mail2_template",
         :subject => "Mail 2").deliver!
```

It works fine up until the point when I add an attachment:

```
attachments["file.pdf"] = File.read("file.pdf")
mail(:to => email1, :template_name => "mail1_template",
         :subject => "Mail 1").deliver!
mail(:to => email2, :template_name => "mail2_template",
         :subject => "Mail 2").deliver!
```

There's nothing wrong with the PDF attachment itself, but, the message that is being received by the email2 recipient, for some non-obvious reason, is being merged with the first one sent to the "email1" recipient: The "email2" recipient receives both email contents in a single email.
Once I remove the attachment line, everything gets back to normal.

How would I fix it?

Comment: Is it happening with email1 also?

Comment: No. email1 is being delivered properly.
By the way, I've noticed that attachment is also getting duplicated, so email2 receives 2 pdf files instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to converse the mails meaning first send email2 and then send email1 -

```
 attachments["file.pdf"] = File.read("file.pdf")
    mail(:to => email2, :template_name => "mail2_template",
             :subject => "Mail 2").deliver!

    mail(:to => email1, :template_name => "mail1_template",
             :subject => "Mail 1").deliver!
```

The reason to do so is to let know that now which email gets both merged mails.

The debugging is helpful too.

Assuming that its your development environment, so don't forget to put the line in your `/config/environments/development.rb`:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

And check the logs from `development.log` to trace where the error actually is.

UPDATE:

Also, you have sent the attachment above the 2 mails. The ruby gets confused as to whom you are going to send attachment i.e. the first email or the other or both. Do one thing- put attachment in between of the two mails and then check the result.

```
    mail(:to => email2, :template_name => "mail2_template",
             :subject => "Mail 2").deliver!

    attachments["file.pdf"] = File.read("file.pdf")

    mail(:to => email1, :template_name => "mail1_template",
             :subject => "Mail 1").deliver!
```

UPDATE:

In order to send attachments to both emails:

```
    attachments["file.pdf"] = File.read("file.pdf")

    mail(:to => email2, :template_name => "mail2_template",
             :subject => "Mail 2").deliver!

    attachments["file.pdf"] = File.read("file.pdf")

    mail(:to => email1, :template_name => "mail1_template",
             :subject => "Mail 1").deliver!
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try and let you know! Thanks

Comment: OK, I've done what you have said, and not only there are no errors, but now email2 is being delivered properly, and the email1 gets merged email content.

Comment: OK, Now the both mail contents are correct (no merging), but email2 doesn't contain the attachment file :(

Maybe there should be some sort of a "flush" function between 2 mail functions, to clear the buffer or something like that ? Hm. I'm confused.

Comment: I didn't knew that you need attachment for both. Check my update again.. :)

Comment: Now it gets merged again :( And, email2 received 2 pdf files :(

Comment: hmm..then the alternative is create two files. One file will contain attachment and email1 and the other file will contains attachment and email2. Then from your controller call method of file1 and then method of file2. Alternatively you can use threads to do the same in background.

Comment: Hm. I've divided my function into two - for each party. If I call them manually, from the console, e.g. MailMailer.send_email1(params), and then MailMailer.send_email2(params) .. it works, but if I create a function, that would call for of these functions, then it is of the same problem again! 
What gives ? ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24172/discussion-between-saurabh-jain-and-dmitri)